# ComponentStatus is deprecated - what to use then

Tags: kubernetes

What do you use instead og kubectl get ComponentStatus?

```
kubectl get cs
Warning: v1 ComponentStatus is deprecated in v1.19+
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this API is deprecated and as it provided status of `etcd, kube-scheduler, and kube-controller-manager` components, which we can get through kubectl or using `/livez` endpoint.

so you can try

```
kubectl get --raw='/readyz?verbose'
#local cluster
curl -k https://localhost:6443/livez?verbose
```

**output**

```
[+]ping ok
[+]log ok
[+]etcd ok
[+]informer-sync ok
[+]poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-admission-initializer ok
[+]poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-consumer ok
[+]poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-filter ok
[+]poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers ok
[+]poststarthook/crd-informer-synced ok
[+]poststarthook/bootstrap-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles ok
[+]poststarthook/scheduling/bootstrap-system-priority-classes ok
[+]poststarthook/priority-and-fairness-config-producer ok
[+]poststarthook/start-cluster-authentication-info-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/aggregator-reload-proxy-client-cert ok
[+]poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller ok
[+]poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration ok
[+]autoregister-completion ok
[+]poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller ok
[+]shutdown ok
readyz check passed
```

> The current state of this API is problematic, and requires reversing the actual data flow (it requires the API server to call to its clients), and is not functional across deployment topologies.
>
> It should be clearly marked as deprecated.

[Mark componentstatus as deprecated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/93570)

> The Kubernetes API server provides 3 API endpoints (healthz, livez and readyz) to indicate the current status of the API server. The healthz endpoint is deprecated (since Kubernetes v1.16), and you should use the more specific livez and readyz endpoints instead.

[using-api-health-checks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/health-checks/)

Comment: Nope, `kubectl get --raw='/readyz?verbose'` doesn't work.  Looks pretty, tells me everything is happy, even though I deliberately broke the scheduler.  `componentstatuses` however, tells me the scheduler is dead.

Answer (score -1):

Just run this and it should work fine.

```bash
kubectl get componentstatuses
```